Why aren't my ipset counters incremented?
I'm trying to configure a firewall (using iptables on a Docker host) that allows inbound HTTP and HTTPS from everywhere, SSH from a certain set of IPs and no other incoming connections. I liked what I read about ipset, as it seems to be easier to configure than raw iptables and also allows easier automated re-configuration of sets. But somehow it does not seem to work: I'm not able to connect via HTTPS, albeit port 443 should be open. SSH connections work (albeit I haven't tried to lock myself out). While trying to debug this issue, I added counters to the various sets in ipset. But they stay at 0, albeit the counters in iptables increase. Why aren't my connections counted in ipset? Are there other/better ways for debugging list:set? And how can I fix it?
Here is the firewall script (intention: allow port 22 from 93.241.223.2, anything on port 80 and 443, and nothing else):
#!/bin/sh

# suffix for set names, to avoid overwriting old sets
timestamp=$(date +%s)

# allow HTTP in general (duplicate sets are due to automated generation of script)
ipset create mds-c-allowhttp4-$timestamp bitmap:port range 0-1024 counters
ipset add mds-c-allowhttp4-$timestamp 80
ipset add mds-c-allowhttp4-$timestamp 443
ipset create mds-c-allowhttp6-$timestamp bitmap:port range 0-1024 counters
ipset add mds-c-allowhttp6-$timestamp 80
ipset add mds-c-allowhttp6-$timestamp 443

# create set with allowed IPv4 ssh connections
ipset create mds-c-allowssh4-$timestamp hash:ip,port family inet counters
ipset add mds-c-allowssh4-$timestamp 93.241.223.2,22
# create set with allowed IPv6 ssh connections
ipset create mds-c-allowssh6-$timestamp hash:ip,port family inet6 counters

# create union of allowed sets
ipset create mds-c-allowcombined-$timestamp list:set counters
ipset add mds-c-allowcombined-$timestamp mds-c-allowhttp4-$timestamp
ipset add mds-c-allowcombined-$timestamp mds-c-allowhttp6-$timestamp
ipset add mds-c-allowcombined-$timestamp mds-c-allowssh4-$timestamp
ipset add mds-c-allowcombined-$timestamp mds-c-allowssh6-$timestamp
# create mds-allowcombined if not already there
ipset create mds-allowcombined list:set counters
# activate new sets
ipset swap mds-c-allowcombined-$timestamp mds-allowcombined

# add iptables rule if not already there
iptables -C DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -m set ! --match-set mds-allowcombined src,dst -j DROP || iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -m set ! --match-set mds-allowcombined src,dst -j DROP
ip6tables -C INPUT -i eth0 -m set ! --match-set mds-allowcombined src,dst -j DROP || ip6tables -I INPUT -i eth0 -m set ! --match-set mds-allowcombined src,dst -j DROP

Here's the output from "ipset --list":
Name: mds-c-allowhttp4-1712053688
Type: bitmap:port
Revision: 3
Header: range 0-1024 counters
Size in memory: 16608
References: 1
Number of entries: 2
Members:
80 packets 0 bytes 0
443 packets 0 bytes 0

Name: mds-c-allowhttp6-1712053688
Type: bitmap:port
Revision: 3
Header: range 0-1024 counters
Size in memory: 16608
References: 1
Number of entries: 2
Members:
80 packets 0 bytes 0
443 packets 0 bytes 0

Name: mds-c-allowssh4-1712053688
Type: hash:ip,port
Revision: 6
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 counters bucketsize 12 initval 0xac582e33
Size in memory: 280
References: 1
Number of entries: 1
Members:
93.241.223.2,tcp:22 packets 0 bytes 0

Name: mds-c-allowssh6-1712053688
Type: hash:ip,port
Revision: 6
Header: family inet6 hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 counters bucketsize 12 initval 0x0bd9d478
Size in memory: 216
References: 1
Number of entries: 0
Members:

Name: mds-allowcombined
Type: list:set
Revision: 3
Header: size 8 counters
Size in memory: 336
References: 2
Number of entries: 4
Members:
mds-c-allowhttp4-1712053688 packets 0 bytes 0
mds-c-allowhttp6-1712053688 packets 0 bytes 0
mds-c-allowssh4-1712053688 packets 0 bytes 0
mds-c-allowssh6-1712053688 packets 0 bytes 0

And here's the output from iptables --list --verbose:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 14268 packets, 12M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
11611   11M f2b-sshd   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 8765  525K DOCKER-USER  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 1939  116K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    br-34e695d35afc  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  any    br-34e695d35afc  anywhere             anywhere
 1939  116K ACCEPT     all  --  br-34e695d35afc !br-34e695d35afc  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br-34e695d35afc br-34e695d35afc  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-34e695d35afc br-34e695d35afc  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:snpp
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-34e695d35afc br-34e695d35afc  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:https
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-34e695d35afc br-34e695d35afc  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere
 1939  116K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-34e695d35afc !br-34e695d35afc  anywhere             anywhere
 1939  116K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    br-34e695d35afc  anywhere             anywhere
 1939  116K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 6826  409K DROP       all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             ! match-set mds-allowcombined src,dst
 1939  116K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
11522   11M RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere


Please better avoid public IP disclosure.

Thanks for the remark. I manually changed the IPs in the example before posting; perhaps I should've written this.

A colleague helped me to understand the problem:

The DOCKER-USER chain is so far only called from FORWARD, not from INPUT. Therefore, the SSH packets do not touch it, only the HTTPS ones do.
The sets of type "bitmap:port" are called with the source port (due to the "src,dst"), not with the destination port. Therefore, they do not match (which is unintended)
The other sets do not match, either. This is intended.
As none of the sets matched, no counter is incremented.
After changing the "bitmap:port" set to "hash:ip,port" for debugging purposes, the counters worked.

Now I just need to find a way to construct the union of a set filtering for source IP and destination port and one filtering for destination port only. But that's another question.

Regarding the last paragraph: With a set of type "net,port", I could construct an "all IPs" wildcard that would filter only by port.
